# How do I convert textBox to int and then do simple math with it in visual studio 2019?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Very new to Visual Studio, and even more with the 2019 version. Just started a windows form app (.net framework), and was wondering how to take something from a textBox, convert it to an int, do some simple math, and then throw the result in a label. Thing is, I haven't found much and I have close to no lead. Here's what happens when I double click the label:

```
Private Sub PTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PTotal.Click

End Sub
```

So, from this I want 2 things: one, I need to add various numbers from a few textBox and make it appear on the label and two, instead of it happening when clicking I need it to happen continuously (I can work around it tho)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: [TextBox.TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged), [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse). See the examples there.

Comment: The `Text` property of a control is where a `String` goes in and out.  That's the critical thing.  What you do with that `String` is irrelevant tot he control and vice versa.  Getting data from a control or into a control is unrelated to what you do with that data in code, so treat them separately and use appropriate search keywords for each.  `Textboxes` have exactly zero to do with maths performed on numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you double click on a control in Design view you get an Event Procedure stub in the code window. What you got is the Click event for the label. Code placed in this sub would run when the label is clicked. Not an event you need for your task.

You probably want a Button control for the user to click when they are ready for the calculation. Call the button btnCalculate in the designer Properties window. Then double click on the button to get a stub for the Click event.

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim number = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    PTotal.Text = (number * 10).ToString()
End Sub
```

Now, what would happen if the user puts their name in the text box instead of a number? Crash bang! So we can check first to see if we have a valid number.

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim number As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) Then
        PTotal.Text = (number * 10).ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The Integer.TryParse method takes 2 parameters. First a string to test, and second a variable to hold the converted value. If the parsing works it returns True so we can use it as a condition in an If statement.

Answer (score -1):

```vb
' get textBox1 Text Data
Dim textData As String = textBox1.Text

' string to int
Dim intTextData As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(textData)

' do something

' int data to label text
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(intTextData)
```

or

```vb
' get textBox1 Text Data
Dim textData As String = textBox1.Text

Dim intTextData As Integer

' string to int
If Integer.TryParse(textData, intTextData) Then
    ' Conversion Successful

    ' do something

    ' int data to label text
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(intTextData)
Else
    'Conversion failed
End If
```